# MySQL Query not updating database

Tags: mysql

Perhaps I am just being a complete idiot but I am trying to insert a record into a MySQL table but it doesn't seem to be working.  When I test it (i.e. get the script to echo the values so I can check that they are being posted by the form), they are being sent but the query isn't posting to the database.  Like I said, perhaps I am being a complete idiot but I felt that perhaps a fresh set of eyes might speed up my troubleshooting because I have been fighting with this issue for the past 2 hours!

Here is the code:

```
// Connects to your Database
  mysql_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpword") or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 

// Get Variables
  $sectorid = $_POST['sectorid'];
  $parentid = $_POST['parentid'];
  $sectorname = $_POST['sectorname'];
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $creon = $_POST['creon'];
  $creby = $_POST['creby'];
  $modon = $_POST['modon'];
  $modby = $_POST['modby'];

//Insert Record
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO cand_emp_sector (sectorid, parentid, sectorname, status, creon, creby, modon, modby)
  VALUES ('$sectorid', '$parentid', '$sectorname', '$status', '$creon', '$creby', '$modon', '$modby)"); 

//On completion, redirect to next page
  header("Location: canddb.new.7i.php");
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try adding `echo mysql_error();` after the mysql_query

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a quote at the end

```
, '$modby')");
         ^---------here
```

Comment: I thought I was being a complete idiot.  It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the result for errors:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cand_emp_sector (sectorid, parentid, sectorname, status, creon, creby, modon, modby)
  VALUES ('$sectorid', '$parentid', '$sectorname', '$status', '$creon', '$creby', '$modon', '$modby)"); 

if($result === false) die('query failed..');
```